# Redirection loop issue using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, webbrowser-control

I have built a chrome extension that converts certain links to an affiliate link and then redirects to that affiliate link.

Steps for better understanding:
1. Someone visits *www.amazon.in* and extension gets it via `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`
2. The url the converted to another url like *www.linkly.com?q1=param&q2=param*.
3. That link again sends the request back to originating url i.e. *www.amazon.in*

Here it is making a redirection loop again and again. I have tried using `types: ['main_frame']` but not getting the solution.

manifest.json:

```js
{
 "manifest_version":2,
   "name": "ExtName",
   "description": "Ext Description",
   "version":"1.0",
   "browser_action":{
  "default_popup":"index.html"
 },
 "icons": {
     "16": "ic_launcher.png",
     "48": "ic_launcher.png",
  "128": "ic_launcher.png"
 },
 "background": {
     "scripts": ["app/background.js","lib/jquery.min.js"],
     "persistent": true
 },
 "content_scripts":[
  {
   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
   "css":["css/styles.css"],
   "js":["lib/jquery.min.js"]
  }
 ],
 "web_accessible_resources": ["css/styles.css"],
   "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*", "storage","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(["prefs"],function(data){
 var obj=JSON.parse(data.prefs);
 uid=obj._userID;    
 updateLinks(uid);
});
function updateLinks(uid){
 var redirUrl;
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
   if(typeof uid!=="undefined"){
    redirUrl = "https://xredir.com/?pub_id=xxxx&subid="+uid+"&source=xxxx&url="+encodeURI(details.url);
   }else{
    redirUrl = "https://xredir.com/?pub_id=xxxx&source=xxxx&url="+encodeURI(details.url);
   }
   if(details.type=="main_frame"){
     return {redirectUrl: redirUrl};
   }
  },
     {urls: ["*://www.flipkart.com/*", "*://www.amazon.com/*", "*://www.amazon.in/*","*://www.jabong.com/*"],types: ['main_frame']},
     ["blocking"]
 );  
}
```

Please help me out of this problem. I thank you for your time and support in advance.

Comment: You can store the url and its tabId and Date.now() in a global object, so you can check if an incoming amazon url was redirected by you in the last 10 seconds (for example) and not redirect it this time.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm thank you for your response. I have tried with storing `tabId`. But the problem with URL is every time a resource is accessed it converts to that URL. so actually the host is maybe same as _www.amazon.in_ but actual URL is different. like  _www.amazon.in/dl_ or  _www.amazon.in/script.js_. I hope you understand.  

Also if you can give an example I will be grateful to you. I am struggling with 5 days now.